# Compare two version numbers with 4 decimal points in PHP

Tags: php

How can i compare two numbers in PHP which have four decimal places.  version_compare does not seem to work with four decimal places.  It will work for three.

Example:
Is a > b
Compare:
a : 16.8.1.22.23
b : 16.8.1.23.40

Is there an easy way to do this ?

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? Works just fine... https://3v4l.org/FvChs

Comment: show your code for calling `version_compare`, where it *'does not seem to work'* ... works for me with all variants i could think of for a 5-part version number.

Comment: It is actually working.. i had a different error in my code.  thanks for the responses

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method

```
mixed version_compare ( string $version1 , string $version2 [, string $operator ] )
```

As third argument you set the comparison operator :
 <, lt, <=, le, >, gt, >=, ge, ==, =, eq, !=, <>, ne

For exemple :

```
if (version_compare('16.8.1.22.23', '16.8.1.23.40', '>')) {
   // do something
}
```

In this exemple it won't enter the if because `$version1` is lesser than `$version2`.

ref : reference documentation for **[version_compare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)**

Comment: You're welcome @newdjango, if it's what your looking for, can you accept the answer and +1 if possible ;)